# return list of dataframe from inside a function to apply rbind using do.call()

Tags: r

Below is a trimmed version of my script. I am hoping my function will return me a list per loop iteration, so that I can rbind all the list to form a new data frame, but when I am executing this script, I keep getting the error:

*do.call("rbind", listofdfs) : object 'listofdfs' not found*

Thank you all for your help.

```
library(DBI)
library(RPostgreSQL)

drv<- dbDriver("MyDataBase")
con<-dbConnect(drv,dbname="DB_Name",
           host="DB_Location",port=number,user="MyName",password= "Password")


dates <- seq(as.Date(as.character(Sys.Date() - 33)), as.Date(as.character(Sys.Date() - 1)), by=1)


my_function<-function(dates){

listofdfs<-list()

for(i in 1:length(dates){

data<-dbGetQuery(con, sprintf("select X,Y,Z from TABLE where date>=date('%s')", dates[i])


data$newColumn<-mean(data$X)

listofdfs[[i]]<-data
}

return(listofdfs)

}

df<-do.call("rbind", listofdfs)
```

I have a small simplified example to refer, please refer to the *dates* variable from above

```
my_list_function<-function(dates){

for(i in 1:length(dates))
{  

my_list<-list()

my_list[[i]]<-i

}
return(my_list) }

k<-do.call(rbind,my_list(dates))
View(k)
```

now running 
     **do.call(rbind,my_list(dates))**
returns error *could not find function "my_list"* and running **do.call(rbind,my_list_function(dates))** works but is only giving 33.

Thanks again for help.

Comment: Wouldn't that need to be `df<-do.call("rbind", listofdfs(dates) )`?

Comment: @42-...this will throw error *could not find function listofdfs*...

Comment: Should have been the name of the function.

Comment: Your query is a bit strange since there will be many, many duplicate rows as you are taking dates on or after a sequential data range then row binding them together. For instance, yesterday's date will be included in day before's and yesterday's rows but different means.

Comment: @Parfait...I only posted part of the full query to avoid unnecessary confusion. To give you a bit more idea, In actual query I am providing a start and end date range and then doing the work on the dataset I received....Thanks for noticing my question....cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listofdfs` is a variable that is declared within your function. Therefore it is not defined outside of its body.

but because it is returned by the function, you can access it by calling the function itself:

```
df<-do.call("rbind", my_function(dates))
```

Also on to make you small example work:

```
my_list_function<-function(dates){
  my_list<-list()
  for(i in 1:length(dates))
  {  
    my_list[[i]]<-i
  }
  return(my_list) 
}

k<-do.call(rbind,my_list_function(dates))
```

Comment: @HubertL....this is working but this returns the last value of the list...also doesn't do.call accepts list as the second argument?

Comment: @HubertL...thanks for explaining the reason for passing function inside do.call, but I am still trying to understand why I am only getting the last value i.e length(dates) and not list with values from 1:33.

Comment: if you copy the code from my post, you should get the list of numbers from 1 to 33 like I do